# Strange behaviour when setting local variables with exec()

Tags: python-3.x

I have a problem with setting local variables with exec.
I know of the drawback of using exec from a security perspective, but this code runs in a controlled environment.

```
def f(e):
    print("Locals before:", locals())
    exec(e)
    print("Locals after:", locals())
```

Output:

```
>>> f('A=3')
Locals before: {'e': 'A=3'}
Locals after: {'e': 'A=3', 'A': 3}
```

Local variable A seems to have been set.

---

I change f to print A it fails:

```
def f(e):
    print("Locals before:", locals())
    exec(e)
    print("Locals after:", locals())
    print("A=", A)
```

Output:

```
>>> f('A=3')
Locals before: {'e': 'A=3'}
Locals after: {'e': 'A=3', 'A': 3}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in f
NameError: name 'A' is not defined
```

---

However this works:

```
def f(e):
    print("Locals before:", locals())
    exec(e)
    print("Locals after:", locals())
    print("A=", eval('A'))
```

Output:

```
>>> f("A=3")
Locals before: {'e': 'A=3'}
Locals after: {'e': 'A=3', 'A': 3}
A= 3
```

---

I also noticed this strange behaviour.

```
def f(e):
    print("Locals before:", locals())
    exec(e)
    print("Locals after:", locals())
    A=locals()['A']
    print("A=", A)
```

Output:

```
>>> f('A=3')
Locals before: {'e': 'A=3'}
Locals after: {'e': 'A=3'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in f
KeyError: 'A'
```

Now A is no longer in the locals dictionary.
Does anyone have an explanation to this?

I am using Python 3.5

Comment: Locals are highly optimised. You can't use `locals()` to change, delete or add to the locals in a function.